# Using a Cisco WebVPN with a CDN

Tags: cisco-vpn, cdn

We have a set of users who access some of our web applications through WebVPN, however where an application uses resources on a CDN e.g. CSS/JS, the url for the resources is being rewritten by WebVPN and then the application fails because it's trying to load files from urls that don't exist.

What changes do we need to make to the WebVPN configuration to make our applications work correctly?